Spark Structured Streaming AvailableNow Trigger end offset on failure?
I wonder what is the supposed to be the behavior of spark structured streaming when using the AvailableNow Trigger and there is a query failure during the query ? More specifically, what happens to the initial end offset set ? Does it change ? While it is clear that using checkpointing the query would resume where it left off, but what happens to the end offset ? To some degree it almost amount to ask if spark structured streaming make difference between a failure and the end of the query ?

Few reads,SO...Good question.
Very simple! Offsets only updated when all processing completes succesfully in all Trigger Modes, actually. Continuous Mode not considered here.
Next invocation results in re-processing, so you need idempotent sinks or intermediaries.
Here https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/apache-spark-structured-streaming-apache-kafka-offsets-management/read is an excellent guide on this.



Next invocation results in re-processing, so you need idempotent sinks or intermediaries ??? that can introduce confusion if not contextualized well.



I mean if you have checkpoint file it make no sense that there will be reprocessing.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/streaming.html#incremental-batch-ingestion

i would love to be pointed to where this update happen, the code that deal with that

That is how it works.

??????? that is not the question

See updated answer.
